# How to go to other forms by clicking a pushButton in Qt Widget Application

Tags: qt, qwidget, qmainwindow

We have 2 ui forms. let's say ***form1.ui*** and ***form2.ui*** with their Header and Source files.
In each form, there are a **pushButton**, a **label** and a variable **QString**. I want to show form2.ui by clicking the pushButton in form1.ui and show the form1.ui by clicking the pushButton in form2.ui.

and the text of the label1 be value of QString2 and the text of the label2 be value of QString1.

**this is the outline:**
[Project outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQnra.png)

**form1.cpp:**

```
#include "form1.h"
#include "ui_form1.h"
Form1::Form1(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form1::~Form1()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**form1.h**

```
#ifndef FORM1_H
#define FORM1_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class Form1;
}

class Form1 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form1(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Form1();
    QString str1 = "some text 1";

private:
    Ui::Form1 *ui;
};

#endif // FORM1_H
```

form2.cpp and form2.h are the same as these.

Can someone please share the code of each file that how this can work.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a bite of of code, to help us help you. Thank you

Comment: The solution most likely should involve the use of signals and slots where your push button triggers a slot in the second ui.

Comment: I actually tried that too. But i wasn't successful to achive the result.